# How to produce a Kafka avro record exactly as like produced using avro console producer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I am using Confluent 3.3.0. My intention is to use kafka-connect to insert values from Kafka topic into Oracle table. My connector works fine with the avro record I have produced using avro console producer like below:

```
./kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list 192.168.0.1:9092 --topic topic6 --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"flights3","fields":[{"name":"flight_id","type":"string"},{"name":"flight_to", "type": "string"}, {"name":"flight_from", "type": "string"}]}'
```

and I insert values like:

```
{"flight_id":"1","flight_to":"QWE","flight_from":"RTY"}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to insert the same data using a Java application, using objects. Below is my producer code:

```
public class Sender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.0.1:9092");
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "serializers.custom.FlightSerializer");
        props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://192.168.0.1:8081");
        Producer<String, Flight> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, Flight>(props);
        Flight myflight = new Flight("testflight1","QWE","RTY");
        ProducerRecord<String, Flight> record = new ProducerRecord<String, Flight>("topic5","key",myflight);

        try {
            producer.send(record).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Flight VO:

```
package vo;

public class Flight {
    String flight_id,flight_to,flight_from;

    public Flight(String flight_id, String flight_to, String flight_from) {
        this.flight_id = flight_id;
        this.flight_to = flight_to;
        this.flight_from = flight_from;
    }

    public Flight(){
    }

    public String getFlight_id() {
        return flight_id;
    }

    public void setFlight_id(String flight_id) {
        this.flight_id = flight_id;
    }

    public String getFlight_to() {
        return flight_to;
    }

    public void setFlight_to(String flight_to) {
        this.flight_to = flight_to;
    }

    public String getFlight_from() {
        return flight_from;
    }

    public void setFlight_from(String flight_from) {
        this.flight_from = flight_from;
    }
}
```

and finally, the Serializer:

```
package serializers.custom;

import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import vo.Flight;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class FlightSerializer implements Serializer<Flight> {
    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> arg0, boolean arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String arg0, Flight arg1) {
        byte[] retVal = null;
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            retVal = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(arg1).getBytes();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

But what I understood is that there is something like schema need to be defined, and use some avro serializer to get the **exact data** like I did using **avro console consumer**. I have gone through some example codes, but none worked for me.

### Edit

I tried the following code. But nothing is coming in avro console consumer.

```
package producer.serialized.avro;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import vo.Flight;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Sender {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String flightSchema = "{\"type\":\"record\"," + "\"name\":\"flights\","
+ "\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"flight_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"flight_to\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"flight_from\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.0.1:9092");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://192.168.0.1:8081");
KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
Schema schema = parser.parse(flightSchema);
GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
avroRecord.put("flight_id", "1");
avroRecord.put("flight_to", "QWE");
avroRecord.put("flight_from", "RTY");
ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record = new ProducerRecord<>("topic6", avroRecord);

try {
producer.send(record);
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: "nothing is coming in avro console consumer." -> do you get an error when you run the java code?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt no, nothing is coming, not even an error. I have restarted kafka server in debug mode, still I am getting nothing.

Comment: KafkaProducer saves the message in a buffer and transmits it later. The program immediately terminates so the transmission never happened. Call the `close()` or `flush()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The schema is not defined so when `KafkaAvroSerializer` will have to contact the schema-registry to submit the schema it will not have it.

You have to create a schema for your object `Flight`

An example of file.avdl (one of avro extension file) below will be fine :

```
@namespace("vo")
protocol FlightSender {

    record Flight {
       union{null, string} flight_id = null;
       union{null, string} flight_to = null;
       union{null, string} flight_from = null;
    }
}
```

See [Avro IDL docs](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/idl.html#defining_protocol)

[At compile time, when you use the `avro-maven-plugin`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html), the avro schema above will generate your java `Flight` class and thus you have to delete the one that you created previously.

When it concern your main class, you have to set the two properties like below:

```
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
```

And your producer, you can use your generated, specific Avro class

```
Producer<String, Flight> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, Flight>(props);
```

Hope that's helping :-)

Answer (score 0):

> exact data like I did using avro console consumer

You can [take a peek at the source code for that](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/formatter/AvroMessageReader.java)

---

Assuming you want to use Generic Records, this all is correct,

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.0.1:9092");
...
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://192.168.0.1:8081");

Producer<String, GenericRecord> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

...

GenericRecord avroRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema);
avroRecord.put("flight_id", "1");
avroRecord.put("flight_to", "QWE");
avroRecord.put("flight_from", "RTY");
ProducerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record = new ProducerRecord<>("topic6", avroRecord);

try {
    producer.send(record);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But you are missing a call to `producer.flush()` and `producer.close()` at the end to actually send the batch of records